# Delphi select object by unknown class type

Tags: delphi, class, types, delphi-7

I have a few different classes which origin is a another class. I have one property that is extended to all other classes.
But different classes handle this property differently. 
So i want to do this:

> TClass(ObjectPointer).Property:=Value;

But TClass is unknown class type

Can i do something like that:

> ObjectPointer.ClassType(ObjectPointer).Property:=Value

or this

```
var
   ClassRef: TClass;
begin

   ClassRef := Sender.ClassType;
   ClassRef(ObjectPointer).DoStuff
   end;
```

Is there way to do this in delphi without using if statement

Comment: Which version of Delphi do you have? I ask because the answer is going to involve run time type information (RTTI), and modern versions of Delphi have better abilities in this arena.

Comment: i use delphi 7 second edition

Comment: @David, even if you have Delphi XE2, still you can use `TypInfo.pas`

Comment: @TLama Indeed, but if you have XE2 then you may prefer to use new RTTI

Comment: Borland never released a product called Delphi 7 second edition to the best of my knowledge. Are you using pirated software?

Comment: @David, but in cost of it's size I would rather rely on the old school style :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Please note, the code from this post will work only for published properties!***

To answer your question *if there's a way to set a property value without using if statement*, check the following overloaded functions.

The first one is for char, string, variant, integer, 64-bit integer, float, enumeration, set and dynamic array type of properties (phew). The second one is just for class type properties. Both will return True if given property exists and the value or object instance is successfuly assigned, False otherwise:

```
uses
  TypInfo;

function TrySetPropValue(AInstance: TObject; const APropName: string;
  const AValue: Variant): Boolean; overload;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    SetPropValue(AInstance, APropName, AValue);
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function TrySetPropValue(AInstance: TObject; const APropName: string;
  AValue: TObject): Boolean; overload;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    SetObjectProp(AInstance, APropName, AValue);
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

And the usage; when the `Memo1.Lines` is set the, the second version of `TrySetPropValue` is called:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Strings: TStringList;
begin
  TrySetPropValue(Memo1, 'Width', 250);
  TrySetPropValue(Memo1, 'Height', 100);
  TrySetPropValue(Memo1, 'ScrollBars', ssBoth);

  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strings.Add('First line');
    Strings.Add('Second line');
    TrySetPropValue(Memo1, 'Lines', Strings);
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;

  if not TrySetPropValue(Memo1, 'Height', 'String') then
    ShowMessage('Property doesn''t exist or the value is invalid...');
  if not TrySetPropValue(Memo1, 'Nonsense', 123456) then
    ShowMessage('Property doesn''t exist or the value is invalid...');
end;
```

Comment: Ok but what i have to do in my class, cuz when i use this always pops an error "Property asd doesn't exist" but i have that published property - property asd:double read ActTime write ActTime;

Comment: The code from this post will work only for `published` properties. Published property doesn't mean only that you have exposed it in a class, it must be in the `published` section.